# What is the difference between if(a == (1,2)) and if(a == 1,2)?

Tags: c, comma-operator

What is the difference between`if(a == (1,2))`  and  `if(a == 1,2)` ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int a = 2;
  if(a == (1,2))
    printf("Hello");
  if(a == 1,2)
    printf("World");

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a == 1,2` is equivalent to `(a == 1),2` due to [*operator precedence*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

And because of how [the comma operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Comma_operator) works, `(a == 1),2` will result in `2`. And `a == (1,2)` will be the same as `a == 2`.

So in effect your two conditions are like

```
if (a == 2)
    printf("Hello");
if(2)
    printf("World");
```

The first condition will be true only if `a` is equal to `2`. The second condition will *always* be true (only zero is false).

Answer (score 2):

In the both conditions of the if statements there is used the comma operator

The second condition is equivalently can be rewritten like

```
if( ( a == 1 ), 2)
```

The value of the comma operator is the value of the second operand. So the condition in the second if statement will always evaluate to true because 2 is not equal to 0.

The condition in the first if statement can be rewritten like

```
if(a == 2)
```

because the first expression (the integer constant 1) of the comma operator has no effect.

So the condition of the if statement evaluates to true only when a is equal to 2.